# node-gyp - hash md5 was not found

Tags: python, angular, npm, openssl, node-gyp

I was recently trying to install Powerlevel9k and its fonts using Powerline Fonts. During the process I was trying to follow the steps to have the appropriate python version etc... Along the lines somewhere I think I completely messed up my whole local python - openssl set up (probably trying some pip command they were having me run). Now I realized I cannot even run npm i on any of my node or angular projects anymore either.

I have tried looked everywhere and tried every fix I could find but nothing seems to work. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling python (latest version, 2.7, and 2.6) also tried switching to using pyenv and relinking python, tried uninstalling and reinstalling openssl using homebrew and pointing bashrc and pointing the compilers to the homebrew openssl, even tried uninstalling nvm and node and reinstalling everything.

Still no luck.

```
> node-gyp rebuild

ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joellyounrajendram/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "/Users/joellyounrajendram/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/joellyounrajendram/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "/Users/joellyounrajendram/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main
    options.duplicate_basename_check)
  File "/Users/joellyounrajendram/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 98, in Load
    generator.CalculateVariables(default_variables, params)
  File "/Users/joellyounrajendram/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 79, in CalculateVariables
    import gyp.generator.xcode as xcode_generator
  File "/Users/joellyounrajendram/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/xcode.py", line 7, in <module>
    import gyp.xcodeproj_file
  File "/Users/joellyounrajendram/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcodeproj_file.py", line 152, in <module>
    _new_sha1 = hashlib.sha1
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sha1'
```

Comment: What method did you use to install yarn? Could you also confirm where the bin is located? `which yarn`